# Bug report conundrum

Tags: bug-reporting

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04.  Like many others, I often get the message on startup "An application has crashed on your system (now or in the past)."  This message is obviously completely unrevealing.  But I do know how to find what's causing it: look in apport.log.

The bug I want to report is simply that the error message is inappropriate and should specifically advise looking in apport.log.  But I haven't been able to figure out how to report this bug.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start here [Wiki on Ubuntu Bug Reporting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)